# MapKit hide POI (park names, building names, etc) doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have `.showsPointsOfInterest` set to `false` in my `viewDidLoad`, I tried setting `.showsBuildings` to `false`, but when I launch the map it still shows all the POI names on the map... Does anyone know why this is still happening?

[image]

my mapView setup code:

```
mapView = MKMapView()

let leftMargin:CGFloat = 0
let topMargin:CGFloat = 0
let mapWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
let mapHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height

mapView?.frame = CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: mapWidth, height: mapHeight)

mapView?.mapType = MKMapType.standard
mapView?.isZoomEnabled = true
mapView?.isScrollEnabled = true
mapView?.showsPointsOfInterest = false
mapView?.showsBuildings = false

mapView?.delegate = self
mapView?.showsScale = true
let scale = MKScaleView(mapView: mapView)
scale.scaleVisibility = .visible
scale.legendAlignment = .leading
mapView?.addSubview(scale)
mapView?.showsCompass = true
self.view.addSubview(mapView!)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug from iOS 10.

https://openradar.appspot.com/28980142

Comment: faaantastic, I'm tempted to put in a code-level support request with apple and ask them what the hell haha